# C++ data sharing between threads c++

Tags: multithreading, c++11, point-cloud-library

Originally coming from Java, I'm having problem with data sharing between 2 threads in C++11. I have thoroughly read through the multithreading posts here without help and i would simply like to know why my approach is not OK C++ syntax for multithreading.

My application in short:

- I have one thread reading a hardware sensor and dumping that data to some shared data monitor
- I want another thread listening to data changes of that very  monitor and draw some graphical stuff based on the new data (yes, I'm using conditional varible in my monitor)

Below is my Main class with the main method:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <sweep/sweep.hpp>
#include <pcl/ModelCoefficients.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include "include/LiDAR.h"
#include "include/Visualizer.h"


void run_LiDAR(LiDAR* lidar){
  lidar->run();
}

void visualize(Visualizer* visualizer){
  visualizer->run();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try {

  Monitor mon;  //The monitor holding shared data

  LiDAR sensor(&mon);  //Sensor object dumping data to the monitor
  Visualizer vis(&mon);   //Visualizer listening to data changes and updates the visuals accordingly

  std::thread sweep_thread(run_LiDAR, &sensor);   //Starting the LiDAR thread
  std::cout << "Started Sweep thread" << std::endl;

  std::thread visualizer_thread(visualize, vis);
  std::cout << "Started Visualizer thread" << std::endl;

  while(1){
      //Do some calculations on the data in Monitor mon
      mon.cluster();
  }
}
```

The sensor thread dumping the data works good and so does the main thread running the clustering algorithms. However I get the following error message:

```
In file included from MY_DIRECTORY/Main.cpp:3: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:336:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<1>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
```

If I comment the line:

```
std::thread visualizer_thread(visualize, vis);
```

My program builds and works...

What am I not getting?

Kind regards,

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to compile the code, but it looks like `vis` cannot be copied.

Comment: Did you mean `&vis`?

Comment: @doctorlove Using `&vis` is somewhat dangerous. You need to make sure that `vis` lives until after the thread is done with it and be careful of race conditions. To avoid this problem `std::thread` makes a copy in the first place.

Comment: Indeed.... just showing where this was going to end up - the code uses `&sensor` (whcih use `&mon`) and there's no thread join...

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that Visualizer doesn't have a move constructor.

```
  std::thread visualizer_thread(visualize, vis);
```

visualize() expects a pointer.

As an aside, you should make you have a mechanism to end your threads in an orderly manner, since the data (sensor, vis) will destroy itself when main() exits, leaving the threads reading/writing to unallocated data on the stack!

Using dynamic allocation using std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr (which are moveable) can eliminate the issue.